Disable javascript auto semicolon
Is there a way to to prevent javascript from auto assuming optional semicolons (in the browser, not node).
I tried to use the strict mode, but that did not help.
Background: I write my code in more or less allman style (new lines for brackets) and this in combination with optional semicolons changes how the code runs:
let f=()=>
{
 // .. something

 return // <- js assumes ; here
 {
  a:varxy
 }
}

So depending on indentation style it returns undefined or the object. In a language that accepts whitespaces, this seems extremely odd. Obviously i like to prevent that.
P.S. please do not start another indentation style war

js assumes ; here it has done so since it was first created, and it will do so forever more - and there's nothing can be done about it

No need to start a war - you've already lost by choosing allman for javascript :-)

The syntax defined in the ECMAScript reference specifically forbids the use of a line terminator between return and any expression that might follow. (MDN Reference)
Whatever you consider the rights and wrongs, your syntax is invalid, and you'll need to adopt valid syntax for your code to work.
if you feel strongly enough you could submit a feature request (the process is described here). Don't expect any changes in the near future. Or at all.

"you could submit a feature request" - see https://es.discourse.group/t/proposal-disable-automatic-semicolon-insertion-looking-for-champion/638 for what some committee members think about automatic semicolon insertion

A feature to prevent ASI or that forces to write every optional semicolon might be good. It would at least prevent js from being ambiguous in such situations.
